# Unable to edit content editor web part even with full control

Tags: 2010, permissions, content-editor-web-part

In SharePoint 2010. Two users are having the same permission (full control) and one of them is able to edit the CEWP without any issues.

However, the other user is unable to edit the CEWP and doesn't even have the small arrow button on the web part.

Does anyone knows what may cause the issue?

Comment: I added ,But I found no luck . Can we implement any solution from developer end ,So that it get's apply to all the users

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer? Try to add the root site of your SharePoint to the "Compability View Settings".

=> Gear symbol in the upper right in IE => "Compability View Settings" ("Einstellungen für Kompatibilitätsansicht" in german)